# Integrating tan x without substitution.

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

A student asked how to integrate tan x and he was trying while using integration by parts.

I taught him the substitution method but he then asked why we can't use integration by parts.
My immediate thought was it is possible just much more complicated but in trying it out, I can't seem to do so.

Is it simply not possible to integrate tan x by parts?

Attached are my workings for the substitution method and the failed attempt at avoiding substitution.

[Integration by substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGjAY.jpg)

[Trial of integration by parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMXfK.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.